# Cumulatively counting up a variable in Stata

Tags: r, list, count, stata

I feel like this is very simple. I have a variable, that goes like this [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1], starting at 0, ticking up and then reset. I need to be able to track which number reset each observation is at. So for that dataset, the values I'd expect are [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]. I can't quite figure this out.

I'm using Stata at the moment, but I swap over to R, if that's easier. I have about half a million observations, so something that doesn't take too long would be appreciated.

Comment: Half a million observations might mean that there is some further structure to your dataset, which would imply more general code, but if so I suggest that you need to tell us about it. Both answers to date answer the question that you asked exactly, which is entirely appropriate, but datasets that size often have other structure too.

Comment: you all are wizards, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stata solution:

```
clear

input foo
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
0
1
end

generate wanted = sum(foo == 0)

list, separator(0)

     +--------------+
     | foo   wanted |
     |--------------|
  1. |   0        1 |
  2. |   1        1 |
  3. |   2        1 |
  4. |   3        1 |
  5. |   0        2 |
  6. |   1        2 |
  7. |   2        2 |
  8. |   0        3 |
  9. |   1        3 |
     +--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, this is very simple using `cumsum`. This basically increments the count whenever a 0 is encountered in the sequence.

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1)
cumsum(x == 0)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R solution using `findInterval`, i.e.,

```
findInterval(seq_along(x),which(x==0))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
```